# How can I load an SWF from a C# EmbeddedResource without first writing to file?

Tags: c#, activex, axshockwaveflash

I'm using the flash 10 activex control to load a flash movie into my WinForm.  Unfortunately, it only takes a path.  What I'm trying to do is load the swf from a stream I can get from an EmbeddedResource so I can embed the swf into my exe such that A) I don't have to worry about paths and B) I don't have my swf quite so exposed - simpler for both usage and deployment.

I know of using [f-in-box](http://f-in-box.com/) but I'd like to not add yet another dependency to my project.  Is there a way to load the swf into the underlying activex control without having to use a path?

I'm using C# and .Net 3.5sp1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that path always a **file** path? Or can it be a URL? It should be pretty simple to set up a temp localhost web-server using `HttpListener` (or similar), that streams back the file in response to an http request.

Another possibility would be named pipes; I wonder if you can convince the control to open a named pipe as though it were a file? (they have a logical file path, after all). I've barely touched these, though - so I can't say 100% whether it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I believe it should be able to accept a URL, but is setting up a localhost webserver very client-friendly?  And I believe named-pipes are simply for passing info from one process to another right?  Flash's activex control only takes a string.

Comment: You won't have to set up a full webserver, just a tcp listener which will respond with a simple, predefined header and the swf content. But you'll need a free TCP port, and a background worker. I guess there's some potential for trouble, but it's not rocket science.

Comment: Not sure if it's the way we're gonna go, but this is the closest solution I've seen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if flash 10 supports the [res protocol](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220830) to load web content from resource. But I think the web browser control in Windows Forms and WPF support it.

To create a native resource you need an editor of native resource. Visual C++ has one. You can use RC.exe in Windows SDK to compile it to res files before linking in your C# program.

Update:
Looks like the flash plugin for IE does not support the res protocol. embed the .swf file in a resource file and have it load using the movie parameter won't work. Try embed the Flash file in a web archive file (.mht) and add the .mht file to your resource.

Comment: I've attempted res and couldn't get it to work.  Neither have I seen any examples on the web of it working.  Thanks though.